# Failed to get clickable element using selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, ui-automation

Here is the scenario, I have multiple tiles on home page. when a user logins in for the first time some of them need to be disabled. Same i am trying to test using selenium.

To disable the div i am using ng-class by which i am applying .disableDiv class on the div which has below css

```
 .disableDiv {
     pointer-events: none;
     opacity: 0.4; }
```

When i target it using .isEnabled() but it is showing true even if the disable class is applied on it.

Please suggest how should i target the disabled elements. 
below as you see isNewUser is ng-class which applies .disableDiv  on the element which makes is disabled for the end user.

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 tile-box-1" id="div-importcontent" ng-class="isNewUser"> 
                        <div class="tile-box-2">   
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 tile-box icon-box">
                                <!-- icon -->
                                <a class="d-icon-download icon" ui-sref="importcontent" id="a-importcontent"></a>
                            </div>   
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 tile-box desc-box">

                                <h4 class="heading" ui-sref="importcontent" id="h4-importcontent">Import content</h4>
                                 <!-- <a class="d-icon-info_circle icon-info"></a> -->
                                <span class="desc" ui-sref="importcontent" id="span-importcontent">Import installed applications reporting content into BMC Remedy Smart Reporting 
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML and your code trials?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Can you sum up your Manual steps you are trying to Automate?

Comment: @MayurRandive isEnabled() checks if the disabled attribute is present. The class disableDiv makes the div to NOT support pointer events ie mouse and sets the opacity to lighter or in other words more transparent. Better option would be to check if the div contains this class.

Comment: @Grasshopper Yes did the same, thank for taking time to efforts :)